# FCL Linking with catkin build

Tags: ros, moveit, catkin, fcl, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just switched from catkin_make_isolated to [catkin tools](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for building ROS from source. I added the `--install` command but I'm getting errors when building MoveIt! in a different workspace after sourcing the ROS installed from source workspace:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIBFCL_LIBRARIES_FULL
    linked by target "moveit_collision_detection_fcl" in directory /home/dave/ros/ws_moveit/src/moveit_core/collision_detection_fcl

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

There is something wrong with FCL or my environment, but I am not sure what to do. I have already built several other workspaces on top of the ROS-installed-from-source one, so it seems to mostly be working. Thanks!

**--- EDIT ---**

Perhaps this might be useful: there were some issues with FCL on this [ROS Answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/80936/why-are-there-entries-in-rosdistro-for-ros-independent-libraries/) and there was a fix in moveit_core as noted in the [changelog](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_core/blob/hydro-devel/CHANGELOG.rst) for 0.5.7

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173227/fcl-linking-with-catkin-build/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2014-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, I figured out my mistake. Although I (later) added the `--install` argument, I had still forgotten to source the `/install/setup.bash` but instead was only sourcing `/devel/setup.bash` like I do for my other, regular catkin workspaces. I guess because the ROS-from-source workspace includes non-ROS packages this is really important.

Thanks jbohren for the help!

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0